# How to troubleshoot application crashes (find a minidump or stacktrace)

Tags: crash, debug

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 on a server, and compiled Povray v3.8.0-alpha.9861167+av620.

It works nicely with some test scenes, but it seems to have a memory leak when rendering my particular scene. It keeps going until 100% of internal memory and swapfile are used, and then it gets killed automatically by the OS.

Is the crash logged anywhere, and can I get a minidump or stacktrace in order to contribute something valuable when reporting the error, or would I have to run it in a debugger/profiler in order to get such info?

Note: I'm not looking for specific advice on how to repair this version (I'll get a stable release). I'd just like to know how to find debugging info in a Linux environment (I'm quite a newbie in that regard).

Comment: Have you tried looking in the journal?

Comment: @j-money Thanks for the "journal" keyword. I went through part of it, it's HUGE... Unfortunately `journalctl --grep=povray` returned `Compiled without pattern matching support` :-(

Comment: you might try doing something like `jouralctl > temp` `cat temp | grep povray`?

Comment: @j-money It's `grep povray temp`, or better yet `journalctl | grep povray`.

Comment: @LouisSomers I just found https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890265#37, so maybe eventually it will end up in Ubuntu as well.