# Where are stacktraces to be found in Ubuntu or how to copy them from the report window?

Tags: bug-reporting, error-handling

I need to copy the stacktrace in this window. Where can I find it?
I tried to observe dmesg and journalctl, found nothing resembling this.
I know how to reproduce error. It is caused by python script calling a library code.
I've also read this: 
[How to troubleshoot application crashes (find a minidump or stacktrace)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084703/how-to-troubleshoot-application-crashes-find-a-minidump-or-stacktrace) but found little help from the info there.

[image: A casual Ubuntu error report window]

Comment: when expanded I see "(binary data)"

Comment: Yes! That's it!
If you would write this in an answer, I would accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs are stored in  `/var/crash/`.

- The reports are named with the directory separated by a "_", a "-", the command, "., user id and end in ".crash".
- command `apport-retrace` can be used to debug ([Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash))